# cannot set property 'innerHTML'

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da forca e quero que mostre as letras ja digitadas corretamente aparecerem a previa nas divs, porém da o seguinte erro no chrome

> forca.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at forca (forca.js:95)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:43)
>   forca @ forca.js:95
>   onclick @ index.html:43

Se eu tento setar todas as palavras em uma div qualquer funciona, apenas do jeito que era pra funcionar não funciona, alguma solução?
Meu código abaixo.

```js
var i;
var quantidadeClasses = 3;
var lastResult;
var palavras = new Array(quantidadeClasses);
for(i = 0; i < quantidadeClasses; i++) {
 palavras[i] = new Array ();
}
/*
 palavras[0] = Veículos
 palavras[1] = Animais
 palavras[2] = Cor
*/

//Palavras Veículos
 palavras[0][0] = "Carro";
 palavras[0][1] = "Barco";
 palavras[0][2] = "Moto";
 palavras[0][3] = "Onibus"

//Palavras Animais
 palavras[1][0] = "Cachorro";
 palavras[1][1] = "Gato";
 palavras[1][2] = "Cavalo";
 palavras[1][3] = "Camelo";
 palavras[1][4] = "Girafa";
 palavras[1][5] = "Golfinho";
 palavras[1][6] = "Macaco";

//Palavras Cor

 palavras[2][0] = "Branco";
 palavras[2][1] = "Preto";
 palavras[2][2] = "Amarelo";
 palavras[2][3] = "Vermelho";
 palavras[2][4] = "Verde";
 palavras[2][5] = "Azul";
 palavras[2][6] = "Cinza";
 palavras[2][7] = "Rosa";

var erros;
var jogada = 0;
var tentativas = 7;
var letra;
var re;
var checar;
var fimJogo;
var maxClasse;
var randomClasse;
var maxPalavras;
var randomPalavra;
var palavra;
var acertos;
var palavraLength;

window.onload = function carregamento() {
 inicioPartida();
}

function inicioPartida() {
 erros = 0;
 jogada = 0;
 acertos = 0;
 fimJogo = false;
 maxClasse = (palavras.length) - 1;
 randomClasse = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxClasse + 1));
 maxPalavras = (palavras[randomClasse].length) - 1;
 randomPalavra = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxPalavras + 1));
 palavra = palavras[randomClasse][randomPalavra];
 palavraLength = palavra.length;
 document.getElementById("teclado").style.display = ""
 document.getElementById("jogarNovamente").style.display = "none";
 for(i = 0; i < palavraLength; i++) {
  document.getElementById("casinha" + i).style.display = "";
 }
}
function forca(letra) {
 document.getElementById(letra).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById(letra).style.color = "#FFF";
 document.getElementById(letra).style.borderColor = "#000";
 document.getElementById("placar").style.display = "";
 if(jogada == 0)
  document.getElementById("avisoTeclado").style.display = "none";
 if(palavra.toUpperCase().indexOf(letra) > -1){
  document.getElementById(letra).style.backgroundColor = "#0F0";
  var lastResult = "acertou";
  document.getElementById("placar").style.color = "#0F0";
  document.getElementById("lastLetra").innerHTML = letra;
  document.getElementById("lastResult").innerHTML = "acertou";
  acertos++;
  for(i = 0; i < palavraLength; i++) {
   var acharLetra = palavra.indexOf(letra);
   document.getElementById("casinha" + acharLetra).innerHTML = letra;
  }
  re = new RegExp(letra, 'gi');
  palavra = palavra.replace(re, '0');
  checar = /^0+$/.test(palavra);
  if(checar == true) {
   setTimeout(function(){ alert("Você venceu. Parabéns!!!"); }, 200);
   document.getElementById("placar").innerHTML = "Você venceu a partida.<br>Caso queira jogar novamente, clique no botão acima para jogar novamente.";
   fimJogo = true;
  }
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById(letra).style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
  document.getElementById("placar").style.color = "#F00";
  document.getElementById("lastLetra").innerHTML = letra;
  document.getElementById("lastResult").innerHTML = "errou";
  erros++;
  if(erros == tentativas) {
   document.getElementById("img").src = "src/boneco/7.png";
   document.getElementById("placar").innerHTML = "Você perdeu o jogo. A palavra correta era " + palavras[randomClasse][randomPalavra] + ".";
   fimJogo = true;
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("img").src = "src/boneco/" + erros + ".png";
  }
 }
 if(fimJogo == true) {
  finalizarPartida();
 }
 jogada++;
}
function mostrarJogar() {
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "";;
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
}
function mostrarTutorial() {
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
}
function gerarDica1() {
 var classe;
 switch (randomClasse) {
  case 0:
  classe = "é um veículo";
  break;
  case 1:
  classe = "é um animal";
  break;
  case 2:
  classe = "é uma cor";
  break;
 }
 document.getElementById("mostrarDica1").innerHTML = classe;
}
function gerarDica2() {
 var primeiraLetra = palavra.charAt(0);
 document.getElementById("mostrarDica2").innerHTML = "Primeira letra: '" + primeiraLetra + "'";
}
function finalizarPartida() {
 document.getElementById("teclado").style.display = "none"
 document.getElementById("jogarNovamente").style.display = "";
}
```

```css
button {
 color: #777;
 background-color: #EEE;
 border: 1px #EEE solid;
}
button:hover {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #DDD;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
} 
ul#navbar {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #EEE;
 border: 1px #DDD solid;
}
li {
 float: left;
}
li a {
 color: #777;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
 background-color: #DDD;
 color: #000; 
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.invisivel {
 display: none;
}
#main {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 550px;
 min-height: 700px;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#logoDiv {
 background-image: url("../src/logo.jpg");
 height: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}
#headerDiv {
 border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}
#bodyDiv {
 margin: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#leftSide {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
}
#rightSide {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}
.center {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}
#teclado {
 width: 370px;
 height: 120px;
 background-color: #DDD;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
#teclado-cima {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#teclado-meio {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#teclado-baixo {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.teclado {
 width: 30px !important;
 height: 30px !important;
}
#dicaDiv {
 margin-top: 5px;
 border: 1px #606060 solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
 padding: 10px;
}
#pDica1 {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#placar {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#avisoTeclado {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#img {
 border: 1px #606060 solid;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.casinhas  {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Jogo da Forca</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/forca.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/mostrar.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="main">
   <div id="logoDiv"></div>
   <div id="headerDiv">
    <ul id="navbar">
     <li id="liJogar" style="background-color: #CCC;"><a href="javascript:mostrarJogar();" id="jogoNavbar">Jogar</a></li>
     <li id="liTutorial"><a href="javascript:mostrarTutorial();" id"tutorialNavbar">Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>

   </div>
   <div id="bodyDiv">
    <article id="jogar">
     <div id="bonecos" class="text-center">
      <img src="src/boneco/0.png" id="img" alt="Boneco">
     </div>
     <div id="teclado" class="center">
      <div id="teclado-cima" class="text-center">
       <button class="teclado" id="Q" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">Q</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="W" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">W</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="E" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">E</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="R" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">R</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="T" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">T</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="Y" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">Y</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="U" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">U</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="I" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">I</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="O" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">O</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="P" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">P</button>
      </div>
      <div id="teclado-meio" class="text-center">
       <button class="teclado" id="A" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">A</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="S" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">S</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="D" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">D</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="F" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">F</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="G" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">G</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="H" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">H</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="J" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">J</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="K" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">K</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="L" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">L</button>
      </div>
      <div id="teclado-baixo" class="text-center">
       <button class="teclado" id="Z" onClick="forca(this.id);">Z</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="X" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">X</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="C" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">C</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="V" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">V</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="B" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">B</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="N" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">N</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="M" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">M</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="resultado" class="text-center">
      <span id="casinha0" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha1" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha2" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha3" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha4" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha5" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha6" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha7" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha8" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha9" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha10" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha11" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha12" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha13" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha14" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
     </div>
     <button id="jogarNovamente" class="center" style="display: none;" onClick="window.location.reload(false);">Jogar Novamente</button>
     <p id="avisoTeclado" class="text-center">Clique em alguma tecla do teclado para jogar.</p><p id="placar" class="text-center" style="display: none;">Você jogou <span id="lastLetra"></span> e <span id="lastResult"></span>.</p>
     <div id="dicaDiv" class="text-center">
      <p id="pDica1" style="display: inline;">Dica 1: <span id="mostrarDica1"><a href="javascript:gerarDica1();" onClick="gerarDica1();">mostrar dica</a></span>.</p><br>
      <p id="pDica2" style="display: inline;">Dica 2: <span id="mostrarDica2"><a href="javascript:gerarDica2();">mostrar dica</a></span>.</p><br>
     </div>
    </article>
    <article id="tutorial" style="display: none;">
     <p>Nesse tópico, você verá como jogar o Jogo da Forca.</p/=>
     <p></p>
    </article>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paulo, qual é exatamente a linha 95? Aparentemente não achou o elemento, por exemplo nessa linha `document.getElementById("casinha" + acharLetra).innerHTML`, pode ser que a junção de "casinha" com a variável **acharLetra** gere um ID que não existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incluí o `acharLetra` na hora em que ele verifica que a letra existe, que é

```
...
if((acharLetra = palavra.toUpperCase().indexOf(letra)) > -1){
  document.getElementById(letra).style.backgroundColor = "#0F0";
  var lastResult = "acertou";
  document.getElementById("placar").style.color = "#0F0";
  document.getElementById("lastLetra").innerHTML = letra;
...
```

Para isso, declarei `acharLetra` um pouco antes, perto do início de `forca()`,

```
function forca(letra) {
  var acharLetra;
  document.getElementById(letra).disabled = true;
  document.getElementById(letra).style.color = "#FFF";
....
```

```js
var i;
var quantidadeClasses = 3;
var lastResult;
var palavras = new Array(quantidadeClasses);
for(i = 0; i < quantidadeClasses; i++) {
 palavras[i] = new Array ();
}
/*
 palavras[0] = Veículos
 palavras[1] = Animais
 palavras[2] = Cor
*/

//Palavras Veículos
 palavras[0][0] = "Carro";
 palavras[0][1] = "Barco";
 palavras[0][2] = "Moto";
 palavras[0][3] = "Onibus"

//Palavras Animais
 palavras[1][0] = "Cachorro";
 palavras[1][1] = "Gato";
 palavras[1][2] = "Cavalo";
 palavras[1][3] = "Camelo";
 palavras[1][4] = "Girafa";
 palavras[1][5] = "Golfinho";
 palavras[1][6] = "Macaco";

//Palavras Cor

 palavras[2][0] = "Branco";
 palavras[2][1] = "Preto";
 palavras[2][2] = "Amarelo";
 palavras[2][3] = "Vermelho";
 palavras[2][4] = "Verde";
 palavras[2][5] = "Azul";
 palavras[2][6] = "Cinza";
 palavras[2][7] = "Rosa";

var erros;
var jogada = 0;
var tentativas = 7;
var letra;
var re;
var checar;
var fimJogo;
var maxClasse;
var randomClasse;
var maxPalavras;
var randomPalavra;
var palavra;
var acertos;
var palavraLength;

window.onload = function carregamento() {
 inicioPartida();
}

function inicioPartida() {
 erros = 0;
 jogada = 0;
 acertos = 0;
 fimJogo = false;
 maxClasse = (palavras.length) - 1;
 randomClasse = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxClasse + 1));
 maxPalavras = (palavras[randomClasse].length) - 1;
 randomPalavra = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxPalavras + 1));
 palavra = palavras[randomClasse][randomPalavra];
 palavraLength = palavra.length;
 document.getElementById("teclado").style.display = ""
 document.getElementById("jogarNovamente").style.display = "none";
 for(i = 0; i < palavraLength; i++) {
  document.getElementById("casinha" + i).style.display = "";
 }
}
function forca(letra) {
    var acharLetra;
 document.getElementById(letra).disabled = true;
 document.getElementById(letra).style.color = "#FFF";
 document.getElementById(letra).style.borderColor = "#000";
 document.getElementById("placar").style.display = "";
 if(jogada == 0)
  document.getElementById("avisoTeclado").style.display = "none";
 if((acharLetra = palavra.toUpperCase().indexOf(letra)) > -1){
  document.getElementById(letra).style.backgroundColor = "#0F0";
  var lastResult = "acertou";
  document.getElementById("placar").style.color = "#0F0";
  document.getElementById("lastLetra").innerHTML = letra;
  document.getElementById("lastResult").innerHTML = "acertou";
  acertos++;
  for(i = 0; i < palavraLength; i++) {
   document.getElementById("casinha" + acharLetra).innerHTML = letra;
  }
  re = new RegExp(letra, 'gi');
  palavra = palavra.replace(re, '0');
  checar = /^0+$/.test(palavra);
  if(checar == true) {
   setTimeout(function(){ alert("Você venceu. Parabéns!!!"); }, 200);
   document.getElementById("placar").innerHTML = "Você venceu a partida.<br>Caso queira jogar novamente, clique no botão acima para jogar novamente.";
   fimJogo = true;
  }
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById(letra).style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
  document.getElementById("placar").style.color = "#F00";
  document.getElementById("lastLetra").innerHTML = letra;
  document.getElementById("lastResult").innerHTML = "errou";
  erros++;
  if(erros == tentativas) {
   document.getElementById("img").src = "src/boneco/7.png";
   document.getElementById("placar").innerHTML = "Você perdeu o jogo. A palavra correta era " + palavras[randomClasse][randomPalavra] + ".";
   fimJogo = true;
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("img").src = "src/boneco/" + erros + ".png";
  }
 }
 if(fimJogo == true) {
  finalizarPartida();
 }
 jogada++;
}
function mostrarJogar() {
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "";;
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
}
function mostrarTutorial() {
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
}
function gerarDica1() {
 var classe;
 switch (randomClasse) {
  case 0:
  classe = "é um veículo";
  break;
  case 1:
  classe = "é um animal";
  break;
  case 2:
  classe = "é uma cor";
  break;
 }
 document.getElementById("mostrarDica1").innerHTML = classe;
}
function gerarDica2() {
 var primeiraLetra = palavra.charAt(0);
 document.getElementById("mostrarDica2").innerHTML = "Primeira letra: '" + primeiraLetra + "'";
}
function finalizarPartida() {
 document.getElementById("teclado").style.display = "none"
 document.getElementById("jogarNovamente").style.display = "";
}
```

```css
button {
 color: #777;
 background-color: #EEE;
 border: 1px #EEE solid;
}
button:hover {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #DDD;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
} 
ul#navbar {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #EEE;
 border: 1px #DDD solid;
}
li {
 float: left;
}
li a {
 color: #777;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
 background-color: #DDD;
 color: #000; 
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.invisivel {
 display: none;
}
#main {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 550px;
 min-height: 700px;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#logoDiv {
 background-image: url("../src/logo.jpg");
 height: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}
#headerDiv {
 border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}
#bodyDiv {
 margin: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#leftSide {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
}
#rightSide {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}
.center {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}
#teclado {
 width: 370px;
 height: 120px;
 background-color: #DDD;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
#teclado-cima {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#teclado-meio {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#teclado-baixo {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.teclado {
 width: 30px !important;
 height: 30px !important;
}
#dicaDiv {
 margin-top: 5px;
 border: 1px #606060 solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
 padding: 10px;
}
#pDica1 {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#placar {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#avisoTeclado {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#img {
 border: 1px #606060 solid;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.casinhas  {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Jogo da Forca</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/forca.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/mostrar.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="main">
   <div id="logoDiv"></div>
   <div id="headerDiv">
    <ul id="navbar">
     <li id="liJogar" style="background-color: #CCC;"><a href="javascript:mostrarJogar();" id="jogoNavbar">Jogar</a></li>
     <li id="liTutorial"><a href="javascript:mostrarTutorial();" id"tutorialNavbar">Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>

   </div>
   <div id="bodyDiv">
    <article id="jogar">
     <div id="bonecos" class="text-center">
      <img src="src/boneco/0.png" id="img" alt="Boneco">
     </div>
     <div id="teclado" class="center">
      <div id="teclado-cima" class="text-center">
       <button class="teclado" id="Q" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">Q</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="W" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">W</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="E" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">E</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="R" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">R</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="T" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">T</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="Y" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">Y</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="U" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">U</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="I" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">I</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="O" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">O</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="P" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">P</button>
      </div>
      <div id="teclado-meio" class="text-center">
       <button class="teclado" id="A" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">A</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="S" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">S</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="D" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">D</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="F" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">F</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="G" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">G</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="H" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">H</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="J" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">J</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="K" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">K</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="L" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">L</button>
      </div>
      <div id="teclado-baixo" class="text-center">
       <button class="teclado" id="Z" onClick="forca(this.id);">Z</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="X" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">X</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="C" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">C</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="V" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">V</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="B" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">B</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="N" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">N</button>
       <button class="teclado" id="M" name="nameTeclado" onClick="forca(this.id);">M</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="resultado" class="text-center">
      <span id="casinha0" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha1" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha2" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha3" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha4" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha5" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha6" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha7" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha8" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha9" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha10" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha11" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha12" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha13" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
      <span id="casinha14" class="casinhas" style="display: none;">_</span>
     </div>
     <button id="jogarNovamente" class="center" style="display: none;" onClick="window.location.reload(false);">Jogar Novamente</button>
     <p id="avisoTeclado" class="text-center">Clique em alguma tecla do teclado para jogar.</p><p id="placar" class="text-center" style="display: none;">Você jogou <span id="lastLetra"></span> e <span id="lastResult"></span>.</p>
     <div id="dicaDiv" class="text-center">
      <p id="pDica1" style="display: inline;">Dica 1: <span id="mostrarDica1"><a href="javascript:gerarDica1();" onClick="gerarDica1();">mostrar dica</a></span>.</p><br>
      <p id="pDica2" style="display: inline;">Dica 2: <span id="mostrarDica2"><a href="javascript:gerarDica2();">mostrar dica</a></span>.</p><br>
     </div>
    </article>
    <article id="tutorial" style="display: none;">
     <p>Nesse tópico, você verá como jogar o Jogo da Forca.</p/=>
     <p></p>
    </article>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou certinho, porém queria entender como o if((acharLetra = palavra.toUpperCase().indexOf(letra)) > -1) funciona desse jeito e o meu modo ali não, poderia dar uma breve explicação? sou novato em js ainda

Comment: uma outra duvida, quando tem 2 letras repetidas ele só pega a primeira, como eu arrumaria isso nesse metodo?

Comment: Você comparou `palavra` com a `letra`, que é maiúscula. E como a comparação é sensível à caixa, ele não achou as letras minúsculas correspondentes, em `palavra`. Faltou colocar `.toUpperCase()`. Como você tinha usado isso uma vez, nesta linha que mostrei, eu só reaproveitei o código.

Comment: Pra achar mais ocorrências da letra na string, é só adicionar um argumento a mais na chamada de `.indexOf()`. Este segundo argumento é a posição a partir da qual você vai procurar. Por exemplo, digamos que você queira saber onde ocorre a letra pela primeira vez; você faz `var primeiraVez = minhaString.indexOf("A");`. Daí, para a segunda ocorrência, você faz `var segundaVez = minhaString.indexOf("A", primeiraVez + 1);`.

Comment: obrigado, consegui alterando o jeito que eu transformava na string a letra achada para 0 e transformando todas as palavras para tudo maisculo. Codigo completo para caso ajude alguem: https://github.com/phgrund/jogo-da-forca

Answer (score 3):

Eu coloquei um console.log antes da chamada problemática e retornou o seguinte: "casinha-1" e seu ID da casinha é "casinha1".

```
for(i = 0; i < palavraLength; i++) {
    var acharLetra = palavra.indexOf(letra);
    console.log("casinha" + acharLetra);
    document.getElementById("casinha" + acharLetra).innerHTML = letra;
}
```

Verifica onde está vindo o '-'

Comment: Provavelmente o `-1` é retornado por `indexOf`, já que este é o valor retornado quando não é encontrada nenhuma ocorrência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Então colocar um IF resolve o problema.

Comment: tentei usar um if mas do mesmo jeito nao deu, a solução abaixo mudou algumas coisas e acabou funcionando :)